# Display a specific value from database in a html

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Im pretty new on making webpages. But i´m doing a homepage with forms to Insert to my database. Thats no problem, my problem is that I want to show a specific column from the last row. And the code that I've got so far is this:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
 Publiceringsdag (OBS! En dag tidigare an foregaende):<br>
 <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","rss","Habb0","kalender");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 $lastPub = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM event ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1")
 or die(mysql_error());
 echo $lastPub
 ?>
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="pub"><br>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You should really consider using mysqli

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is not a very good idea to use the deprecated [`mysql_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions. Look at [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`Mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Meanwhile, in your current implementation you just need to fetch your data after the query execution:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "rss", "Habb0", "kalender");

if (mysql_connect_errno())    
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

$lastPub = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM event ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1")
  or die(mysql_error());

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($lastPub)))
    $result = $lastPub['pub'];
```

Now the result should be in your `$result` variable.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that in your code you use `mysqli_connect`, `mysqli_connect_errno` and `mysql_query`, `mysql_error` at the same time. But they belongs to different PHP extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch the result first:

```
$lastPub = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM event ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1")
 or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_array($lastPub);
echo $result['pub'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    <html>
<body>

<form action="insert.php" method="post">
 Publiceringsdag (OBS! En dag tidigare an foregaende):<br>
 <?php
 $con=mysql_connect("localhost","rss","Habb0") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $db=mysql_select_db("kalender",$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT pub FROM event ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
 $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 echo $data['pub'];
 ?>
 <br>
 <input type="text" name="pub"><br>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

 </body>
 </html>
```